# How to permanently rename "Virtual Drive" in "Google Drive for Desktop"?

Tags: windows-10, google-drive, virtual-disk

While using multiple accounts in `Google Drive for Desktop`, the `virtual drives` that are created have long disk names of the email account associated with the drive like `mydrive@gmail.com -  Google Drive (G:)`.
We can rename them as we rename folders but effect is as long as we shut down the system.

So, is there a way to rename them permanently so that the virtual disk name remains same as we restart our PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct solution so, I made a simple script to rename label and run them during startup.

```
label G: Cloud Drive
label H: Cloud Drive
label I: Cloud Drive
```